# How to fix MatCardComponent is not found even though it is imported in the module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a Angular nrwl nx project with bootstrap 5 and Angular material.I have a dashboard compoenent inside a library where I import the MatCardModule but if I try to use it inside my DashboardComponent i am getting the following error:

```
1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

But the funny thing is I already imported it like this in die Dashboard Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', component: DashboardHomeComponent}
    ]),
    MatCardModule,
  ],
  providers: [UserRouteAccessService],
  declarations: [DashboardHomeComponent],
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

This is how my html looks where I am trying to use it:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>Simple card</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

I installed material with npm install bootstrap works just fine.

Comment: Be sure that app.module.ts imports DashboardsModules?

Answer (score 0):

Add DashboardHomeComponent to exports

```
exports: [DashboardHomeComponent]
```

Comment: sadly this did not help

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that the module(DashboardModule) is imported to app.module.ts.
Usualy I check one the follow way. I launch the application, then change anything in imported module(add a space for example and save). If you application is being rebuilded it means that the module imported. If it didn't happen, it means that your module are not imported.